# Angular js dynamic binding in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I am using [Angular Material File input](https://github.com/shuyu/angular-material-fileinput)

```
<div layout layout-wrap flex="100" ng-repeat="val in UploadDocuments">
    <div flex="100" flex-gt-sm="45">
        <div class="md-default-theme" style="margin-left:40px; color: #666666">{{val}}</div>
        <div style="margin-top:-8px;">
            <lf-ng-md-file-input lf-files='$parent.files' lf-api="stimg" ng-disabled="!enableFileBrowse"> </lf-ng-md-file-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to generate `lf-files='$parent.files'` dynamically like `lf-files='$parent.file1'` , `lf-files='$parent.file2'`, `lf-files='$parent.file3'` based on `ng-loop`

The following trick is not working

```
lf-files='$parent.file{{$index}}'
```

How can I generate dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
lf-files='$parent["file" + $index]'
```